# Change color in a SWF

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm using a swf widget to create a image gallery on a website, the problem is, that i cant get to have the color to be changed.

You can find the widget here, in a zip, when putted on a web server ( i use wamp ), works great, simple etc.

If you look at the bottom of the project page, you'll find a devlopper's note that say:

> *I have included a few flash vars, if they are not provided there are defaults in the code. Here are the flash vars:flashvars.xmlPath = “xml/data.xml”; flashvars.backgroundColor = “0×000000″; flashvars.labelColor = “0xFFFFFF”“xmlPath” is the path to the XML file. “backgroundColor” is the color of the background. “labelColor” is the color of the text label in the middle of the coverflow.*

The problem is, that when i try to change this var to another value in their index.html example source, it dont work.
Even if i delete some chars in the var "xmlPath", it still use the content of xml/data.xml. its seems that the developpers made a mistake in their implementation.

As i'm not familliar with js neither with flash, i ask your help to change the background color of this app from black to #0C021D  ..

I tried a flash swf decompiler, with no success, does anyone have a tips ?

Thanks in advance.

here's the index.html source code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>CosDesign</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="Design" href="css/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        flashvars.xmlPath = "xml/data.xml";
        flashvars.backgroundColor = "0x00FF00";
        flashvars.labelColor = "0x006368"
        var params = {};
        params.loop = "false";
        params.menu = "false";
        params.quality = "best";
        params.scale = "noscale";
        params.salign = "tl";
        var attributes = {};
        swfobject.embedSWF("swf/main.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "590", "300", "10.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myAlternativeContent">
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: does the browser show any javascript error? can you paste the full html/javascript code?

Comment: No error at all, .. i use the example source code gived by devloppers, i edit my post to paste the source code.

Comment: hmm... try to set the color to "0x0C021D" instead "#0C021D", maybe the flash is not recognizing the '#'

Comment: Its what i do, in fact my code here is the example one, modified.. in the original, backgroundColor is set to 0x000000 and the labelColor to 0xFFFFFF